Do Named HTTP clients use the same policy handlers instances?
Do HTTP policies instances are shared when I create named HTTP client in each request using IHttpClientFactory?
I am using the IHttpClientFactory to create a named-http-client per request:
var workloadHttpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(product.ToString());
var response = await workloadHttpClient.SendAsync(message);

I am defining named-clients, and Polly's Circuit Breaker per such client:
services
    .AddSingleton<IProductProvider, XProvider>()
    .AddHttpClient(Products.X.ToString())
    .AddPolicyHandler(BuildCircuitBreakerPolicy());

services
    .AddSingleton<IProductProvider, YProvider>()
    .AddHttpClient(Products.Y.ToString())
    .AddPolicyHandler(BuildCircuitBreakerPolicy());

With this definition, will the circuit breaker work?
Will all the created clients named "X" use the same instance of the circuit breaker policy, thus really counting all the failures from all executions of XProvider?

The AddPolicyHandler calls the AddHttpClientHandler to register a PolicyHttpMessageHandler under the hood. This handler is a DelegatingHandler.
Whenever you use HttpClientFactory then the underlying HttpClientHandlers (and the associated DelegatingHandlers) are cached for 2 minutes by default.
That means whenever you create a new HttpClient with the same name then a cached HttpClientHandler will be used. After 2 minutes elapses then the handler is marked as to-be-cleaned. Whenever a new HttpClient with the same name is requested then a new HttpClientHandler will be created.
Here you can find a simplified demo to show you that the CB indeed breaks on the second HttpClient instance:
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Polly;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var collection = new ServiceCollection();
        collection.AddHttpClient();
        collection.AddHttpClient("A")
            .AddPolicyHandler(GetCircuitBreakerPolicy());
        var sp = collection.BuildServiceProvider();
        var factory = sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
        for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var client = factory.CreateClient("A");
            var res = await client.GetAsync("http://httpstat.us/500");
            Console.WriteLine(res.StatusCode);
        }
    }
    
    static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetCircuitBreakerPolicy()
        => Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
            .HandleResult(res => res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
            .CircuitBreakerAsync(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
}


If you want to change this 2 minutes caching period then please check the HandlerLifetime of the HttpClientFactoryOptions.

If I understand you correctly:

HTTP client (also named) are re-created on every factory.CreateClient request.
Handlers are re-created after 2 minutes
Policy are re-used permanently during the entire app lifetime

is that correct?

@Omer 1. Yes, everytime when you call the CreateClient it will create a brand new HttpClient instance. BUT the underlying HttpClientHandler is reused. The typed HttpClient works a bit differently. The DefaultTypedHttpClientFactory has a cache .


Yes, by default the handlers are reusable only for 2 minutes. But that can be adjusted via the HandlerLifetime, via SetHandlerLifetime. You can set this to InfiniteTimeSpan so the handlers will never expire. But this will prevent the handler from reacting to DNS changes.



No, whenever a new HttClientHandler is created then the registered PolicyHttpMessageHandler will be also recreated, so the policy lifecycle is the same as the handler recycling period. PolicyRegistry could be alternative solution here: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyRegistry.


IMHO recreating a CB in every X minute is not that problematic if the CB's consecutive failure count is low and the individual requests are decorated with timeout policy as well.  That means there might some short period when the CB should be open and short cut the execution but it counts the failures instead.

Thanks! We ran your code above with debugging, and marked the object ids of the policy itself, and the http policy handler. Seems like the the policy itself doesn't change when the policy handler is recycled (after 2-3 minutes). Are we sure it should be?

@Omer Sorry my bad, the policy is not recycled. Its lifecycle is handled outside of the PolicyHttpMessageHandler as it is provided as an input parameter for the AddPolicyHandler.

so everything is recycled, and the policy is reused. thanks!

@Omer Yes, correct.

@Omer Do you have any further questions? If not, please consider to mark the post as the answer.
